# As the entire site to specify a title?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a website, but the customer wanted to install on all pages of a title, I do not want to climb throughout the site and change the title of each map, as sdealt for the whole site?

Comment: What is your question?  If you just need to specify a `title` for your HTML across the whole application, surely you can do that in `_Layout.cshtml`, no?

Comment: but if it is overridden in the View of the result is lost

Comment: Well, yes.  That's true.  Do all of the views override this value in the application?  If that's the case then it sounds like a refactoring might be in order to consolidate the titles where appropriate.

Comment: For me, this task is no longer relevant, but I'm wondering whether you can do it.

Comment: I realized my stupidity, you can simply remove ViewBag.Title

Comment: why dont you use a simple notepad editor like "Editplus" or "Notepad++" and use the find and replace option, say for around 30 views it should not take more than 5 minutes...

Comment: because yasser that is bad design, sure its possibble but its better to refactor so you make 1 change once not 1 change many times